# Set Logged in Welcome Message for Customer

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I have Created a Custom Ajax Login Form so that Customer can login using that form.
I am sending ajax post to controller and controller set user as logged in
this is controller code.

```
<?php
class Test_Check_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

public function validatecustomerAction(){

            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); 
            if ($session->isLoggedIn()) { 

                return; 
            } 

            $result = array('success' => false); 

            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
            { 
                $login_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username'); 
                $login_pass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password'); 


                if (empty($login_name) || empty($login_pass)) { 
                    $result['error'] = $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
                } 
                else 
                { 
                     try 
                    { 


                        $session->login($login_name, $login_pass); 
                        $result['success'] = true; 
                        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
                        $result['redirect'] = Mage::getUrl('*/*/index'); 



                        } 

                    catch(Exception $e){

                        $result['success'] = false; 
                        return 0;


                    }


                } 
        } 


            $this->_redirect(''); 

        }

}
```

Now i want to set Welcome message with logged in customer with logout link instead of login link,how can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

karan , i have modify your codes....

```
<?php
class Test_Check_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{


    public function validatecustomerAction(){
        $result=array();
         $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); 
        if($session->isLoggedIn()){
            $result['isloggedin']=true;
        }
        $session=$session;
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
            $login_name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username'); 
            $login_pass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password'); 
            if(!empty($login_name) && !empty($login_pass)){
                try{

                    $session->login($login_name, $login_pass);
                    $result['success']=true;
                    $result['message']= Mage::helper('customer')->__('Login successfull');

                    if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                        $myMess=$this->_ajaxwelcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                        $result['success']=false;
                        $result['message']=$myMess;
                    }

                }catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e){
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login_name);
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                            $result['success']=false;
                            $result['message']=$message;

                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            $result['success']=false;
                            $result['message']=$message;
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            $result['success']=false;
                            $result['message']=$message;
                    }

                }catch(Exception $e){
                    $result['success']=false;
                    $result['message']=
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }



            }else{
                $result['success']=false;
                $result['message']=$this->__('Login and password are required.');
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

    }
   protected function _ajaxwelcomeCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $isJustConfirmed = false)
    {   $MessageOwn= '';
        $MessageOwn= $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName());

        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
            $isJustConfirmed ? 'confirmed' : 'registered',
            '',
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
        );

        return $MessageOwn;
    }


}
```

After that you get data using

```
jQuery.ajax( {
url : youruel,
dataType : 'json',
type : 'post',
data : 'data',
success : function(response) {

/*response.success  will  give flag logged or not 
and response.message give notification that means welcome flag */ 

}
```

});